# Suffering to finalise adjusting a biblatex style

Tags: biblatex

I have almost succeeded adapting a `biblatex` style.

Here is the last steps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend = biber, natbib, maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames=99, minnames=1, giveninits, style=ext-authoryear, innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{: }
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \space}{}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1%
}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}





\newenvironment{hanglist}[1][\parindent]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-#1}}
    }{%
        \end{list}
    }

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{key,
    address = {Vienna},
    edition = {Österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften},
    title = {Cremation burials in {Greece} from the {Late} {Bronze} {Age} to the {Early} {Iron} {Age}: continuity or change?},
    booktitle = {Brandbestattungen von der mittleren {Donau} bis zur Ägäis zwischen 1300 und 750 v. {Chr}.},
    author = {Ruppenstein, Florian},
    editor = {Lochner, M. and Ruppenstein, Florian},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {185--196},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

This is the good reference \citep{key}.

\printbibliography

\noindent Expected output:

\begin{hanglist}[4ex]
\item
\textsc{Ruppenstein}, F. 2013. Cremation burials in Greece from the Late Bronze Age to the Early Iron Age: continuity or change?, in M. Lochner \& F. Ruppenstein (ed.) \emph{Brandbestattungen von der mittleren Donau bis zur Ägäis zwischen 1300 und 750 v. Chr.}: 185--196. Vienna: Österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften.
\end{hanglist}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, it is a bit long, but there are some last points which I have difficulty adjusting as seen in the attached image.
[image: Screenshot showing the differences]

Can somebody help me finalising, maybe cleaning a bit my script?

Comment: Moving the pages in the bibliography is a bit tricky. Especially if we need to take care of other possible fields that could be printed in an entry, but are not printed in the example. I won't have time to look at that tonight. But at https://gist.github.com/moewew/fb6ab27d0a96f27253175ce04655c5f5 there is a slight clean-up of your current code.

Comment: Thank you so much moewe. Am I correct that reference lists in bib latex can be modified by blocks of fields. I cannot find where these “super blocks” are defined and if they are style-dependent.

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to think of the output being controlled by blocks. You will find the drivers in the `.bbx` file of your style. In your case start with https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/release/ext-standard.bbx. That file inherits definitions from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def.

Comment: Suppose you need to give the `edition` (and possibly also have a `series`+`number` field) for the entry. Where does it go w.r.t. the pages field here?

Comment: Edition should go with the booktitle, such as here: Zohary, D., M. Hopf & E. Weiss. 2012. Domestication of plants in the Old World: the origin and spread of domesticated plants in Southwest Asia, Europe and the Mediterranean Basin (4th edition). Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Comment: The guide for author does not say more and I have not yet found an appropriate example.